# How to create different types of variables in a loop?

Tags: c++

I need to add two types `int` and `auto` to the loop. But maybe I want to add a couple more types. Maybe I can use lambda.

I need the best way to implement this.

```
for(int i, auto h; i < 10; i++)
{                             }
```

Comment: What are you going to do with them?  Do they need to live for the entire loop or do you only need them per iteration?

Comment: What would `auto h` even mean?  And you need to initialise `i`.

Comment: `auto` is not a type.

Comment: This question needs a bit more. Consider adding why you need this to the question. There may be alternatives to the overarching problem that you have overlooked.

Comment: auto h this vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't declare multiple types in the for loop initialiser.

Bearing in mind that you *can* initialise them, a reasonable alternative is

```
{
    Foo h;
    for (int i = 0, h = Foo(); i < 10; ++i){
    }
}
```

where the outer braces stop `h` from leaking into the surrounding scope. Another idea would be to use a `std::tuple` or similar.

Comment: changed his mind how it works {
}

Comment: so can i do?
`{ auto h;
   int i;
   for(;;i++)
   {           }
}`

Comment: @user: No; what would be the type of `h`?

Comment: I liked your option more, thanks

Comment: auto h - this vector

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)

like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    for(std::pair<int,std::string> p = std::make_pair(0,"X"); p.first <10 ; p.first ++)
    {
        std::cout<<p.second<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you can also use structured bindings. Nice.

Comment: Thanks a good example but complicated for me

Comment: Was worth an upvote though!